# Build Java Application when using environment vars in application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, maven-3

I have developed a Spring Boot Starter API. The API connects to MySql Database.
My application.properties:

```
# MySQL Connection
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_URL}/${MYSQL_DB_NAME}
spring.datasource.username=${MYSQL_USER}
spring.datasource.password=${MYSQL_PWD}
```

During testing I inject the vars with my IDE (IntelliJ) in the Run -Configuration.

When I try to build a docker image using `mvnw spring-boot:build-image` I get an error, that I get an error `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure`  during test

I assume that maven tries to connect to the db and has no vars to replace the placeholders.

**How can I build the image without including the connection-details in the image ??**

Comment: This is because you are executing the tests also. You should skip the test https://www.baeldung.com/maven-skipping-tests

Comment: Is it generally a good idea to skip tests ? I decided no configure an in memory db-connection (H2) for the tests.

Comment: It's a bad idea to have tests which have dependency on infrastructure, so if you have bad tests then you may need to skip them. But well designed tests which use mocking, in memory servers etc, will not need you to skip tests

Comment: I agree- the executed tests are the standard tests of spring boot